# how to prepare csv data using associated model with missing values in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I'm trying to prepare a csv file which'll be generated from multiple tables.
So I've my model setup like bellow

```
# Student
# attributes
:id, :name 

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
end

# Question model
# attributes
:id, :question

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
end

# Answer model
# attributes
:id, :question_id, :student_id, :answer

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :student
end
```

Now I want to prepare a csv file.The header of the csv file will be the actual  `question` of the `Question` model sorted(by id) and then prepare the csv data accordingly from `Answer` modoel .Now student might not answers all the questions.So I need to set `n/a` if a student doesn't answer a particular question. Offcourse the questions are sorted by id and the answer is also sorted by `question_id`. The output will be.

```
what_is_you_name, how_old_are_you, what_is_your_hobby
monsur, 18, playing football
ranjon, n/a, gardening
n/a, n/a, running
```

I query the `Answer` model.Because some of the `Student` skipped few question therefor there are no answer object present that's why the answer is in wrong position.

```
what_is_you_name, how_old_are_you, what_is_your_hobby
monsur, 18, playing football
ranjon, gardening
alex,running
```

So I need to set `n/a` if the particular student skipped a question .
I can't figure it out how to solve this problem.

Comment: Write a class that takes an Question instance and returns a serializable hash. AKA a serializer.

Answer (score 0):

You could overwrite attribute ie. if `Answer` model has field `age` you could do sth like:

```
def age
  self.age || "n/a"
end
```

This should return age if it's present or "n/a" if it's nil.

If this does not solve your problem please provide a way how do you create CSV.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem.
Here is what I did
questions = Question.all.pluck(:question)

Comment: Please provide structure of these three models and example records and how you want to create CSV from `questions` variable you mentioned above.

Comment: Here is what I tried
    questions = Question.all.pluck(:question)
    temp_arr = []
    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
    csv << questions
    Student.all.each do |student|
      csv << student.answers.order(question_id: :asc).pluck(:answer)
       
  end
end
Hope you understood what I wanted to do.

Comment: I added the attributes of each model hope this'll help you understand the problem.

Comment: `answer` field in an `Answer` model is a string ie. "monsur, 18, playing football" or "ranjon, gardening"?

Comment: monsur is the name of the string pardon me please the code is 

`csv << [student.name, student.answers.order(question_id: :asc).pluck(:answer)].flatten`

so here "monsur, 18, playing football"  >> monsur is the name of the student.
18 is the answer object of the question "how_old_are_you". "playing football" is the answer attribute of the question "what_is_your_hobby"

Comment: So this `student.answers.order(question_id: :asc).pluck(:answer)` should return array of 3 records if student answered all questions right? When he answers only two, then you want to put `n/a` in place of missing answer right? Would be helpful if you could provide example answer object with all values.

Comment: When he answers only two, then you want to put n/a in place of missing answer right? Yes exactly.
`[#<Answer id: 1, student_id: 1, question_id: 1, answer: "18">,
#<Answer id: 2, student_id: 1, question_id: 2, answer: "playing football">,
#<Answer id: 3, student_id: 2, question_id: 2, answer: "gardening">] ...`

Answer (score 0):

Ok after your explanation i came up with sth like this:

1. Create default array `default = ['n/a', 'n/a', 'n/a']`
2. You should add `:question_id` to `.pluck` like here:
   `answers_arr = student.answers.order(question_id: :asc).pluck(:question_id, :answer)` it gives you sth like `[[1, "18"], [2, "playing football"]]`
3. Replace values in default array with values from pluck:
   `answers_arr.each { |e| default[e[0] -1] = e[1] }` so `default` should look like `["18", "playing football", "n/a"]`

EDIT
Here is a code from the comment below that solved problem:

```rb
response = [] 
all_response = [] 
qs_id = [1,2.3]

answers.each do |answer|
  qs_ids.each do |q_id|
    if answer.question_id == q_id
      response << answer.answer
    else 
      response << 'n/a'
    end 
    if qs_ids.last = q_id 
      all_response << response 
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: Great idea, this solution didn't worked directly but it gave me the idea to solved my problem.Thanks so much.So what I did is `
response = []
all_response = []
qs_id = [1,2.3] 
answers.each do |answer|
qs_ids.each do |q_id| 
if answer.question_id == q_id
response << answer.answer
else
response << 'n/a'
end
if qs_ids.last = q_id
all_response << response
end
end
`

Comment: I skipped some of the code here. 
Thanks again for your idea you can change the answer accordingly so that I can accept @stolarz